# Need to find a Fourier Series...

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fourier-series, transformation

I am to find a Fourier Series for the following function:

$$
y(x)=\sqrt {R^{2}-x^{2}}
$$

about
$$
-R \leq x \leq R
$$

with the recursion
$$
y(x+2R)=y(x)
$$

Do I let$\sqrt {R^{2}-x^{2}}$equal $y$ in this circumstance and proceed to find coefficients $A_0, A_n, B_n$?

Answer (score 3):

You have an even function of $x$, so you will have a Fourier series of the form

$$y(x) = a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k \, \cos{\left ( \frac{\pi k x}{R}\right )}$$

where

$$a_0 = \frac{1}{2R} \int_{-R}^{R} dx \, \sqrt{R^2-x^2} = R \frac{\pi}{4}$$

$$a_k = \frac{1}{R} \int_{-R}^{R} dx \, \sqrt{R^2-x^2} \, \cos{\left ( \frac{\pi k x}{R}\right )} = R \frac{J_1(k \pi)}{k} $$

where $J_1$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of first order.

Comment: I'm trying to deduce the fourier integral into the bessel integral now.  Using the Bessel Integral:  $J_1(x) = \frac {1} {\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} cos(\tau-xsin\tau)d\tau$, and letting $x=k\pi$, how is the inner cosine angle obtained to produce $R\frac {J_1(k\pi)} {k}$?

Comment: @Gerg: substitute $x=R \cos{t}$, etc.